# PowerBuilder: Checkbox in DataWindow

Tags: checkbox, powerbuilder, sqlanywhere, datawindow

I have a checkbox in the DataWindow, It can be checked and unchecked. The default value in the db is 0. When it's checked, the db value is updated to 1 and on uncheck, the value is updated to 0 again.

However, I want to update the database only if it has value 0. If it is already 1, then I don't want the user to be able to change it back to 0. So please tell me how can I do that?
Here is the code from my DataWindow for the checkbox column:

```
column=(type=decimal(0)  update=yes updatewhereclause=yes name=ok dbname="table.ok"  values="1/0"  )
```

Answer (score 2):

You could protect the checkbox to prevent unchecking it : in the `general / protect` field of your checkbox :

```
if(ok = 1, 1, 0)
```

Once the checkbox has been checked, it becomes protected (you still have to update the data to the base).
On the next retrieve, you can see that the checkbox is already protected.

You might have to use a similar expression for the `Pointer` to show that the field is blocked, for example with the `NoPointer!` cursor.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I pasted the expression `if(ok = 1, 1, 0)` in the protect expression box, but it gives error `Expecting true/false expression`. Do I need to select something from the functions or columns boxes? I'll appreciate your help.

Comment: @Billa this is weird... If you replace the `ok = 1` by `true` or `false` does it protects or unprotects the checkbox permanently ? If so, what you have type in the test part of the `if()` is not a logical test...

Comment: Try typing it in. Sometimes pasting from web pages gets you weird characters (non-breaking spaces and such). Another way is to first paste to a text editor like Notepad++ to see what is actually there.

Answer (score 0):

try using:
 `if( upper(ok) = 'OFF', 1, 0)` 
or the other way around:
 `if(upper(ok) = 'ON', 1, 0)` 
depending on how you set the on/off values in the properties of the check box.

**Note** I'm using PowerBuilder 2017